# SDL.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, include, package, sdl

I've installed `libsdl 1.2 -dev` on my Ubuntu but the problem is that it doesn't understand 
`#include<SDL.h>`

And it says:

```
SDL.h: No such file or directory
```

But when i type:

```
kit0n@ubuntu:~$ g++ sepand.cpp -o sepand -lSDL
```

The project compiles without any problems.
What should I do to make Ubuntu understand SDL.h?

Comment: `SDL.h` and `sdl.h` are not the same thing - your code and error message don't match, please correct that. Also your question is not clear - where does it work and where doesn't it? If the g++ command you quote works, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't work when it's `SDL.h` but it works with `SDL/SDL.h` the problem is that i can't change the code so i have to make it work with SDL.h

Comment: Then add `-I/usr/include/SDL` (or wherever that include directory is located on your machine) to your compile commands (before the source file name).

Comment: IS there some way that i dont need to do it before every compile?
cause this thing that i'm talking about is a program that has some functions related to SDL so i don't exactly COMPILE something i run a program

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Headers are only used at compile time. If you are getting that error, you're compiling something. And if you're compiling, you need to tell the compiler where the headers are.

Comment: Mat is correct. Make sure to include `/usr/include/sdl` and to link against `SDLmain` and `SDL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The correct way](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/FAQLinux#How_do_I_add_SDL_to_my_project.3F) is to add `` `sdl-config --cflags` `` to your CXXFLAGS. (You should also add `` `sdl-config --libs` `` to your LIBS even thou it doesn't seem to be needed in your case.)

Paraphrasing from the link: use the output of the command `sdl-config --cflags --libs` for SDL 1.2 or `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` for SDL2, for example:

```
gcc -o test test.c `sdl-config --cflags --libs`
```